# How to import own class in test - kotlin

Tags: spring, gradle, kotlin

I want to add some tests to my project, but I don't see my classes. Why?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1,
    topics = [ServiceControllerTest.EXAMPLE_TOPIC])
class ServiceControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var receiver: Receiver
}
```

E.g.: I can't import and use Receiver.

Comment: This is really hard to answer without more context. If you gradle is set correctly up your tests should depend on your source code. If so this might be an issue with your IDE not reading the gradle configuration correctly. Often you can add IDE plugins (e.g. "idea" for IntelliJ, and "eclipse" for Eclipse) to your gradle config to get proper support for the tests

Comment: Like @RohdeFischer says, we need more context to provide a good answer. Can you share your `build.gradle` or `pom.xml`?